# Grails - No class def found error when calling web service

Tags: web-services, grails, groovy, groovyws

*Updated to reflect new error message after changes*

Howdy, I am trying to call a web service from Grails, but keep running in to errors.

Here's what my class looks like:

```
import groovyx.net.ws.WSClient
```

...

```
    def serviceUrl = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL"
    def proxy = new WSClient(serviceUrl.toString(), this.class.classLoader)
    serviceResult = proxy.FahrenheitToCelsius("80")
    println serviceResult
```

...

I am encountering a grails runtime exception:

***Error 500: Executing action [index] of controller [myPackage.myController] caused exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/endpoint/Client***

Have been trying to troubleshoot, but have been unable to find any helpful resources.  Any help or suggestions on how to remedy would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the `new` operator it looks like:

```
def proxy = new WSClient(serviceUrl.toString(), this.class.classLoader)
```

Comment: Big oversight by me, haha... however a new error now exists:


Error 500: Executing action [index] of controller [myPackage.myController] caused exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/endpoint/Client

Comment: That looks like you're missing a dependency...  how are you getting the required libs on the classpath?  Using `@Grab` like it says on the documentation works for me... http://groovy.codehaus.org/GroovyWS

Comment: Getting an 'error grabbing grapes' runtime exception while trying to run the grails application if I include that @Grab line.  Saying org.codehaus.groovy.modules#groovyws;0.5.2: not found.  I had already put groovyws-0.5.2.jar in my lib file, and I thought it was being imported, but I'll try fussing around with that @grab to see if I can get it working.

Comment: Just putting the single jar in lib won't be enough...  It has a fair few dependencies: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy.modules/groovyws/0.5.2 (26 of them)

Comment: Thanks Tim... was able to find all the dependencies I needed and the call is now working!