# Grails Unable to consume web service using Wsclient

Tags: grails, groovy, ws-client

I have used WSClient on my Grails application by adding groovyws-standalone-0.3.1.jar in lib folder of my project. 
Added the following code in my controller:

```
import groovyx.net.ws.WSClient
....
....

def wsdlUrl = "url_Of_webservice?wsdl"
def payLoad = "list_Of_Parameters"
def result = ''
def proxy = new WSClient(wsdlUrl , this.class.classLoader)
try{
     proxy.initialize()
     result = proxy.getallvendorsbyurl(payLoad)                      
}
catch (java.lang.NullPointerException e){
      println "proxy not initialize"
 }
```

It is working fine in localhost but when i deploy it on tomcat6 server, it starts throwing exception :

On server logs:

```
 ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport
```

On GSP page:

```
Error 500: Executing action [groupDetails] of controller [com.ongraph.yhd.GroupController]  caused exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovyObjectSupport
Servlet: grails
URI: /grails/group/groupDetails.dispatch
Exception Message: groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport
Caused by:groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport
Class:GroupController
At Line: [758] (groupController->line-758->def wsdlUrl = "url_Of_webservice?wsdl")
```

I have also gone through the below mentioned link but no luck :(

[link to a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105461/grails-no-class-def-found-error-when-calling-web-service)

Comment: which grails version are you using?

Comment: I think you need to follow this: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+WSClient+in+Grails, but what's more is that groovyws is 'dormant'. Its authors recommend that you use https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used grails ws-client plugin and it worked like a charm.